# Hibernate - Why shouldn't we use FETCH JOIN with scroll()?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm reading the Hibernate Documentation (version 5.1), and I'm falling on this sentence :

> Fetch joins should not be used in paged queries (e.g. setFirstResult()
>   or setMaxResults()), **nor should they be used with the scroll() or**
>   iterate() features.

(http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join)

I've recently work on a project with a big database (2To) and for many batch treatments we doesn't have any other solution than to use `FETCH JOIN` with the `scroll()` method (or we have to leave Hibernate and go back to full SQL query).

I understand that paged queries can't garanty that we have a complete result (while fetching a collection for example).

But when using scroll() (which rely on databases cursors if I'm not making a mistake), if we sort the result by the root entites Ids, I can't see a reason why Hibernate can't garantie the result's coherence and completeness.

What is the reason of that restriction ?

What is the risk for the data fetched ?

Is there a way to prevent it ? (like sorting by ids root entities ?)